# PHP sum with same reference number

Tags: php, mysql, select, sum, html-table

First of all, I have a table called store_00

```
id | ref | item | qty | cost | sell 
1     22    x1     5     10     15
2     22    x2     10    5      10
3     23    x11    2     4      6
4     23    x22    1     5      10
5     24    x8     1     1      2
```

Now I want the output to be like this :

```
             | ref number 22 |
total cost = 100 | total sell = 175 | total qty = 15

             | ref number 23 |
total cost = 13  | total sell = 22 | total qty = 3
```

and so on...

Please note I have to **multiply each cost and sell to its qty** because the above table shows unit price...That's what makes my whole code messed up, it would be easier if I do `SUM(qty), SUM(cost) , SUM(sell)` ! but in my case the results will be different.

**PHP code :**

```
$query2 = "SELECT * from store_00 GROUP by ref";
$result2 = mysql_query($query2);
While($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2)){

$ts = $row2['sell'] * $row2['qty'];
$ta = $row2['cost'] * $row2['qty'];
$sumts += $ts;
$sumta += $ta;
$sumqty += $row2['qty'];

echo "<table width=60% height=% align=center border=1 bgcolor=#FFFF99>";

echo "<tr><td align=center><font style='font-size:17px; font-weight:bold;'>TTL QTY = ".$sumqty."</font></td>";
echo "<td align=center><font style='font-size:17px; font-weight:bold;'>TTL Cost = ".number_format($sumta, 2, '.', '')." JD</font></td>";
echo "<td align=center><font style='font-size:17px; font-weight:bold;'>TTL Sell = ".number_format($sumts, 2, '.', '')." JD</font></td></tr>";
echo "</table>";

}
```

according to the above code, the output seems only takes the first value from each grouped ref like this :

```
     | ref number 22 |
total cost = 50 | total sell = 75 | total qty = 5
```

I don't know how to find a way to multiply values then sum them up and group reference all at once, if you have different method of doing it please share it!

Comment: I've tried it and it didn't work, empty table shown only :/ . Although it looks correct to me.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/60e6e/1

Comment: Thanks Man, it works like a charm !

Comment: Caution: @fusion3k's answer would fail in most RDMS's. Aggregate queries should not include unit level that are not specified in group by. For a true ANSI answer, remove the asterisk in fiddle answer. Default mode in [MySQL 5.7](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html) includes *full group by*.

Answer (score 1):

*It is possible* to use SUM on the product of two columns.

```
SELECT
    ref,
    SUM(qty) as total_quantity,
    SUM(qty*cost) as total_cost,
    SUM(qty*sell) as total_sell
FROM `store_00` 
GROUP BY ref
```

If you use this query, you should not need to do any of the math in PHP.